# Is there any way to account for the GPS ping delay and predict where the user will be no matter how fast the user is?

Tags: swift, gps, core-location

Basically the iPhone pings the satellite once every second when you use the 'BestForNavigation' accuracy. The problem I am having is the faster the user goes, the gap between the cllocations is bigger (as you would expect given the delay), so ideally I'd like to predict where the user will be in an array of location that I already have because the user will be doing the same route I have in the array, so to sum it up:

1. I have an array of CLLocations, a route.
2. The user goes on the same route of the array of locations.
3. Problem: The user starts going fast(+20km/h) then the location coming from the GPS (delayed) doesn't represent where the user actually is in the array of locations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might be possible to get the user's speed, and estimate their distance to/from the last/next location.

Comment: This is really confusing. When you get a location update, that is where the user actually is at that moment. Please clarify what your problem is and what you are trying to do.

Comment: That's only true if you go slow as you haven't moved much from your previous location but if you are going 100 miles x hour and the satellite gives you a location every second, you have travel quite a bit since the last update. My question is how to predict where the user will be and account for that delay knowing that I already have an array of locations where the user is traveling in so if there's a corner, a turn  I can account for that and not just predict on a straight line. I know it's confusing but imagine zip line and a kid holding it and then the kid starts running; kid will be ahead

Comment: If what you say is true then why do all mapping apps work even while going 100mph in my car? The reason those apps work is because when I get a location update it is telling me where are I am at that very moment. It's not where I was 1 second ago. Sure, during the next second between updates, the user will move but when the next update comes, that is where the user actually is at that moment. So is your goal simply to predict where the user might be between updates?

Comment: For a very rough approximation you'd need to get the past 2 positions (to get the direction), the velocity a which it was going in the last point and and move the position to the point resulting from moving in a straight line in the direction calculated, for 1 second, at the speed you had. This is very inexact though. Curves are a problem in this case, but it might be enough for you.

Comment: You can use a Kalman or alpha-beta filter. I would start with the alpha-beta filter as it's easier to implement.